# Get JSON from url gives Error [object object] not found

Tags: jquery, json

I am requesting a JSON data from a url but its giving error as

**GET http://localhost:10560/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)**

```
   var mydata;
$.getJSON({
    url: 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=City,Country&callback=?&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=1111111111111111',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        mydata = data;
        console.log(mydata);
    }
});
```

How to get the json file and parse it?

Comment: In your code the Url is http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx while in error it says http://localhost:10560/[object%20Object]
are you sure, you are not missing anything...

Comment: Looks like you have posted the wrong ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of jQuery.getJSON() is incorrect, docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Use either:

```
var mydata;
$.getJSON("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=City,Country&callback=?&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=1111111111111111",function(data){
   console.log(data)
})
```

OR:

```
var mydata;
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=City,Country&callback=?&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=1111111111111111',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function (data) {
       mydata = data;
       console.log(mydata);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check it here one way to do this - [Consume Service Jquery Json](https://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/consuming-webservice-net-json-using-jquery/)